# factory_boy: make a factory that returns the result of a function

Tags: python, factory-boy

I have a function that generates a list of objects. The objects have complex relationships that are handled in the generator function.

How do I make a factory (not a SubFactory!) that, when asked to generate a value, just calls this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, a simple `factory.Factory` will simply call its `Meta.model`, using the parameters as kwargs.

For instance, in order to call [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), one could use the following factory:

```py
class ProcessFactory(factory.Factory):
  class Meta:
    model = subprocess.run

  class Params:
    # Require the program being passed separately from its options.
    program = "ls"
    opts = ()

  args = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: [o.program] + list(o.opts))

  check = True
  capture_output = True
```

and use it as:

```py
>>> ProcessFactory(opts=["-a", "-h", "."], cwd="/tmp")
CompletedProcess(...)
```

As you can see:

- The factory simply called the function provided in `Meta.model`, passing all declarations as kwargs, and returned the function's return value;
- Fields declared in [`class Params`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#parameters) aren't passed to the function;
- One can freely use all kinds of factory_boy declarations.

If your function expects positional arguments, the [`Meta.inline_args`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.FactoryOptions.inline_args) option can be used to convert kwargs into positional arguments.